# Subtraction of large numbers golang

Tags: go, biginteger

I did not think that I would have to write about it, but nowhere can I find at least an example of subtracting large numbers

So I have two numbers and I want to subtract them, the library says that there is only a limit on memory, however, when I try to subtract two 256-bit numbers I get an error.

Tell me what to do with it and how to solve it?
I began to study Go, everything seems to be so cool, however I constantly encounter similar questions. What's wrong.......

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/big"
)

func main() {
    a := big.NewInt(113792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007908834671645)
    b := big.NewInt(20277110887056303803699431755396003735040374760118964734768299847012543114150)
    c := big.NewInt(0).Sub(a, b)
    fmt.Println("c =", c)
}
```

Output:

```
*prog.go:9:18: constant 113792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007908834671645 overflows int64
prog.go:10:18: constant 20277110887056303803699431755396003735040374760118964734768299847012543114150 overflows int64*
```

I'm using go version go1.12.4 linux/amd64

this code in playground:
https://play.golang.org/p/AY8Z8kkCRdg

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you need to be using `big.Int.SetString` in your code. Here's a playground link, works there: https://play.golang.org/p/HvEke4g7e8V

For those who don't want to click a link:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/big"
)

func main() {
    a, _ := new(big.Int).SetString("113792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007908834671645", 10)
    b, _ := new(big.Int).SetString("20277110887056303803699431755396003735040374760118964734768299847012543114150", 10)
    c := big.NewInt(0).Sub(a, b)
    fmt.Println("c =", c)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

mde.... .......

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/big"
)

func main() {
    i := new(big.Int)
    i.SetString("113792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007908834671645", 10)
    k := new(big.Int)
    k.SetString("20277110887056303803699431755396003735040374760118964734768299847012543114150", 10) 
    c := big.NewInt(0).Sub(i, k)
    fmt.Println("c =", c)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/AuGj9A93FbP